# what type of modules/features/functionalities should be included in front-end development

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

I'm doing web applications, business applications and websites, etc. so animation, forms, ui-grid are all concerns.

I have done the least amount of unit test ever possible in development cycles, and because I used angularjs, unit testing is supposed to be easy.

Besides the usual calculations and string manipulations what type of things should I unit test? Features? Modules? How does front-end unit test come into play?

Comment: it is more important to do e2e test for the front end provided that you use SOA for the backend.

Comment: as in the flow of the pages?